# How can I efficiently check, if vector a contains same elements than vector b

Tags: c++, vector

I search for an efficient way to look if vector A contains same elements than vector B. Both vectors have different sizes and each element is another vector with two elements (x and y coordinates). I need the position of the equal Elements in vector A.
At the moment I am doing it with for loops, but the vector b can have up to 8000 elements and my program is really slow at the moment.
I read about the algorithm library, but I could not find something that would help me or I did not understand it.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> VecA; 
std::vector<std::vector<int>> VecB; //size of VecB >> VecA

for( int i = 0; i < VecA; i++)
{
   for( int z = 0; z < VecB; z++)
   {
     if (VecA.at(i) == VecB.at(z))
     {
       Do Something with VecA.at(i)
     }
   }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

Comment: @user657267 The OP needs the indices of the matches. If you sort the vectors goodbye original positions.

Comment: Can you change the order of elements in those vectors?

Comment: When you get this working consider replacing the inner, coordinate vector with a std::array<int>.  This wil eliminate one level of indirection and associated overhead.

Comment: I can sort VecB, but not VecA

Comment: *I need the position of the equal Elements in vector A*  Please explain why you need these positions.  Maybe knowing what you're really trying to accomplish on a high-level would produce better solutions.

Comment: I want to work with the non equal elements in my program. They are Pixels in a image, that I yet not have checked. Where the euqal elements are already checked.

Comment: @Schmelix  So you're only using the position as a temporary means of solving a larger problem.  How many elements are there?  Maybe sorting temporary vectors and using `std::set_intersection`, and then working on the result of that would be the solution (as suggested already).

Comment: @Schmelix *but the vector b can have up to 8000 elements and my program is really slow at the moment.* -- Make sure you are running an optimized build (not a "debug" or unoptimized build).  8,000 elements is small.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- don't use a `std::vector<int>` for a pair of values, use a `std::pair<int,int>` or a custom structure
- don't use `std::vector` if you want a fast way to check if a collection contains an element from the other, but a different data structure, eg a `std::unordered_set<Coordinate>`

With a `std::unordered_set<Coordinate>` everything would be much more efficient. Suppose:

```
struct Coordinate {
  int x;
  int y;
}
```

Now provide a custom `std::hash<Coordinate>` specialization that creates a `size_t` from your `Coordinate` object and use `std::set_intersection` or a custom loop that compares the elements.

If you have some range restriction about coordinates, so that both `x` and `y` fit 16 bits (eg. `[0,65536)`) then hashing is trivial (`x << 16 | y`), and what's better is that it's unambiguous (two elements with same key will be the same element), which gives more room for optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

1. Sort both the vectors - that takes O(log(N)) operations.
2. Iterate over both the sorted vectors together and compare them. If you find a match, increment both iterators. If they don't match, increment the iterator that is less. This should take O(N) operations.
3. Stop when one of the iterators reaches the end.